# printf + uint_64 on Solaris 9?

Tags: c++, c, printf

I have some c(++) code that uses sprintf to convert a uint_64 to a string.  This needs to be portable to both linux and Solaris.

On linux we use %ju, but there does not appear to be any equivalent on Solaris.  The closest I can find is %lu, but this produces incorrect output.  Some sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#ifdef SunOS
typedef uint64_t u_int64_t;
#endif

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    u_int64_t val = 123456789123L;

#ifdef SunOS
    printf("%lu\n", val);
#else
    printf("%ju\n", val);
#endif
}
```

On linux, the output is as expected; on Solaris 9 (don't ask), it's "28"

What can I use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have have inttypes.h available you can use the macros it provides:

```
printf(  "%" PRIu64 "\n", val);
```

Not pretty (I seem to be saying that a lot recently), but it works.

Answer (score 7):

On a C99 compliant system:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

uint64_t big = ...;
printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", big);
```

See section 7.8 of the C99 standard.

The specifiers are {PRI,SCN}[diouxX]{N,LEASTN,MAX,FASTN,PTR}

Where PRI is for the printf() family, SCN is for the scanf() family, d and i for signed integral types; o,u,x,X are for unsigned integral types as octal, decimal, hex, and Hex; N is one of the supported widths; LEAST and FAST correspond to those modifiers; PTR is for intptr_t; and MAX is for intmax_t.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on whether your code is actually C or C++. In C, you should be using an `unsigned long long` rather than another type (this is conformant to the current standard, and `long long` is pretty common as far as C99 support goes), appending `ULL` instead of `L` to your constant, and using (as has been mentioned) `%llu` as your specifier. If support for C99 doesn't exist, you may want to check the compiler documentation, as there is no other standard way to do it. `long long` is guarateed to be 64 bits at least.

Comment: uint64_t is every bit as standard as unsigned long long.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%llu` for long long. However, this is not very portable either, because `long long` isn't guaranteed to be 64 bits. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can get `uint64_t` from `stdint.h` if you want to avoid the SunOS conditional typedef.

Comment: But you also need PRIu64 from <inttypes.h>, and that includes <stdint.h>.